# Abs failed on evaluating nested complex expressions

Tags: complex, core-language

I am a new Mathematica user and try to use its power to do some cool stuff. 
I want to draw a fractal graph with `DensityPlot`the length of outcome of `z->z^2+c`, where `z` and `c` are both complex numbers, and `z` is initially 0. I try to combine my knowledge of nested function and delayed-value to accomplish this, here is my code.

```
p[x, y] = x + y*I
f[z_] := z^2 + p[x, y]
DensityPlot[
Abs[Nest[f[p[x, y]], p[x, y], 10]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Then, nothing appears on the graph. I isolate the nested function, and it works well.

```
Nest[f[p[x, y]], p[x, y], 10]
```

> ```
> (x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 +I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[(x + (x + I y)^2 + I y)[x + I y]]]]]]]]]]
> ```

However, it turns out that `Abs` does not give numerical values of these complex numbers, even when x,y are given values.

```
Table[N[Abs[Nest[f[p[1, 1]], p[1, 1], 2]]], {x, 1}, {y, 1}]
```

> `{{Abs[(1. + 3. I)[(1. + 3. I)[1. + 1. I]]]}}`

Please help me know where have I done wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Nest` statement makes no sense. Anything immediately preceding a set of square brackets must be a function and what is inside of the square brackets must be a valid argument to that function.

```
Clear[p, f, x, y]
```

You should use patterns on the LHS of the definition of `p`

```
p[x_, y_] = x + y*I; 

f[z_] := z^2 + p[x, y];
```

I am guessing that you intend `f` to be the function used in the `Nest`

```
Abs[Nest[f, p[1, 1], 10]] /. {x -> 1., y -> 1.}

(*  2.02639*10^254  *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Added `ColorFunctionScaling`

```
DensityPlot[
 Abs[Nest[f, p[x, y], 10]],
 {x, -2.5, 1.5}, {y, -2, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  The `ContourPlot` of the `Log` of the function

```
ContourPlot[
 Log@Abs[Nest[f, p[x, y], 10]],
 {x, -2.5, 1.5}, {y, -2, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image]

Comment: This really does help me!!! Thanks! So Nest can only pass to a single argument, right?

Comment: @Dumb_Mouse - the "single" (second) argument to `Nest` can be a list provided that the function (first argument) accepts a list as its argument and returns a list as its output.

Answer (score 1):

You left out the underscores for the argument of the function p

```
p[x_, y_] = x + y*I
```

Nest[f[p[x, y]], p[x, y], 10] has faulty arguments.

Look at f[p[x, y]]  results in f goes to require 2 arguments ( x + yI)^2+ (x + yI).  2 arguments because now f need x and y

Nesting to p[x,y] will not work because p delivers only satisfy one of the arguments.  This is why you get the square bracket in the Nest...

Comment: This explains a lot, thanks.